# Can't create C++ class object in qml "Cannot assign object to list property "data""

Tags: c++, qt, qml, shared-libraries

I have a painful problem, that I wasted a lot of time for. I need help, because I don't have any idea already.

Here it is. I'm writing qt quick application using qml in Qt Creator on Windows 8.1. Created my own C++ class with name "one". Registrated it via:

```
qmlRegisterType<One>("OneClass", 1, 0, "One");
```

In qml file I imported it:

```
import OneClass 1.0
```

By now everything worked very well. But then I decided to create shared library, where I put my "One" C++ class. Created separated project as New project->Library->C++ Library. Built library with name "mainlib", everything was fine. Connected this library to my application by adding strings in .pro file:

```
DEPENDPATH += ../lib/mainlib
INCLUDEPATH += ../lib/mainlib
LIBS += -L../lib/build-mainlib-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/release -lmainlib
```

Run project and that's moment when I've got this problem:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>
> qrc:/main.qml:18 Cannot assign object to list property "data"
>
> ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file C:\Program >Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 341

Piece of my "one.h" file:

```
#ifndef ONE_H
#define ONE_H

#include "mainlib_global.h"
#include <QObject>

class MAINLIBSHARED_EXPORT One : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString  port_number READ get_port_number WRITE set_port_number)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString  port_speed READ get_port_speed WRITE set_port_speed)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString  x READ get_x WRITE set_x)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString  y READ get_y WRITE set_y)

public:
    One();
    ~One();

    QString get_port_number(void);
    ...

signals:
    void portOpened(QString str);
    ...

private:
    QString port_number;
    QString x;
    QString y;
};

#endif // ONE_H
```

"mainlib_global.h":

```
#ifndef MAINLIB_GLOBAL_H
#define MAINLIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(MAINLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MAINLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MAINLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MAINLIB_GLOBAL_H
```

"mainlib.pro":

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = mainlib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MAINLIB_LIBRARY

SOURCES += one.cpp

HEADERS += one.h\
        mainlib_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Piece of my "main.qml" file, where I declared my object of One class:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0
import OneClass 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 720
    minimumWidth: 930
    color: "lightgrey";
    property bool connected: false
    
    // Object declaration
    One {id: objOne}
    ...
    }
```

Piece of my "main.cpp" file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include "one.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::c());
    qmlRegisterType<One>("OneClass", 1, 0, "One");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```

My application's .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

DEPENDPATH += ../lib/mainlib
INCLUDEPATH += ../lib/mainlib
LIBS += -L../lib/build-mainlib-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/release -lmainlib

QT += qml quick serialport
CONFIG += c++11

win32: RC_ICONS += icon.ico

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    #one.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    #one.h
```

Here is the thing if uncomment "one.h" and "one.cpp" to compile them alongside with application, this problem don't appear and everything works fine. But when comment them to work with library, I get this "Cannot assign object to list property "data"" problem.

I've tried to connect library via right click on project->Add Library, but result is the same. I've read documentation about this "data" property, tried to explicitly assign object declaration to "data", but got the same. Tried:

```
resources: [
    One {id: objOne}
]
```

And got "cannot assign object to list property "resources"". I'm just exhausted with solving this problem. I described you almost every my step, because I think that maybe I do something in wrong way? I'm begging for help...

Comment: What is the content of `one.h`?

Comment: @Patrizio, I added content of `one.h` to my post.

Comment: Shall we guess what is One and what `resource` relates to?

Comment: @folibis, `One` is my C++ class, that I registrated as qml type. I thought according to the strings `qmlRegisterType<One>("OneClass", 1, 0, "One");` and `import OneClass 1.0`, it should be obvious. I tried to assign `objOne` to `resources` everywhere, where it was possible.

Comment: I guess that you problem is `resource`, not `One`'s declaration. But you didn't specify what is it and to what object it related.

Comment: At the begining I didn't use `resource` at all. I declared object as shown in `main.qml` above. I read that [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-item.html#data-prop) and decided to explicitly assign to `resources`. But it didn't work as well. I tried assigning to different qml objects that I have in my application.

Comment: Can you try a QML file that just instantiates the `One` element?
I.e. just the import for `OneClass` and an empty `One {}`
Btw, your properties are read/write but lack the `NOTIFY` signal that QML needs to update property bindings

Comment: @KevinKrammer, I commented everything except import for `OneClass` and declaration `One {}` in my `main.qml`, then run project and got no errors! I hope it'll help you to help me) Because I don't know what to do with that...

Comment: Did you add `DEFINES+=MAINLIB_LIBRARY` to your MainLib's pro file?

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. Can you create a ZIP file with a minimal buildable example that shows the problem?
The fact that it builds would indicate that the symbol export/import of the library is fine, that it ran fine with QML being just `One {}` would indicate that the registration is fine.
Maybe also try putting the `One` element inside an `Item` and that into the `Window` instead of `One` being a direct child of `Window`

Comment: @Tim, yes, I did. I added content of my `mainlib.pro` file to the post.
@KevinKrammer, I've already tried this trick with `Item` and it didn't work. 
[HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycs76l88zhs20ho/example.rar?dl=0) is link for example you asked me.

Comment: What if you remove `one.h` and `one.cpp` from the `MFL` project, and rebuild everything?

Comment: @Mitch, did what you said and rebuilt with library, problem is still here.

Comment: @HermanY., worked for me.

Comment: @Mitch, did you have exactly the same problem? I did it again, but now in release mode. It runs, but doesn't see object's properties. `TypeError: Property 'open_port' of object One(0x2caac18) is not a function`. In debug mode I have the initial problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to declare a new property and bind it to a new 'One' component:

```
Window {
    property One objOne: One { }
}
```

**BUT** as you will see this may cause other (threading) problems. Don't do it!

I **strongly** advise you to use the Qt built-in plugin mechanism. It is designed to do exactly what you want: importing external dynamic QML libraries. 
Check the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind. But I just can not understand why my variant doesn't work? I think using library is the same as compiling project alongside with the class, nothing changes. There is also documentation about shared libraries: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html.
And even wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application. Should be not a problem.

Comment: Using a static library is the same as compiling alongside with the class. Dynamic libraries are a bit different. If you really need a dynamic qml lib, create it like described in the doc. This will also reduce the dependency between both projects.

Comment: Redone it as plugin. Everything works fine in release mode, but in debug I have an error: `plugin cannot be loaded for module`. Put in debug dir plugin folder from release. But it doesn't work. As I understand plugin is compiled as ordinary library, that can be used in other projects, even not qml? Only difference is that it's connected as plugin?

Comment: Oh, I'm totally silly. I was trying to use released plugin in debug mode. Rebuilt plugin in debug mode and everything started work. Thx for help!